# simple way of describing / tagging files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ls, tags

Is there a quick and simple way to tag files in bash so that a list like this one

```
-rw------- 1 root   88039 Sep 29 16:31 7CCE2EC3-3191-4379-C036-1C48CCCE4C6C
-rw------- 1 root 1985554 Sep 27 16:09 61C6DCDC-04C6-5137-8894-2C8930251D1E
-rw------- 1 root  248965 Sep 26 14:12 22384DC7-D60E-57CC-94C2-C5301C980990
-rw------- 1 root  293908 Sep 22 18:27 C14E6C74-C301-49CC-C625-070721CC47C1
-rw------- 1 root  120965 Sep 19 19:17 2407C1C5-D09C-41E1-9080-C2CC8C86D0CC
-rw------- 1 root   20036 Sep 13 18:32 78691D77-C4E6-4ED1-8119-C09CCC194892
-rw------- 1 root   11789 Sep 12 23:16 8C8C190C-5340-421C-96D1-D4111C5E062C
-rw------- 1 root    1884 Sep 11 22:07 CCC91959-9744-4339-9C99-0C75E301090C
```

becomes something like this (or similar)

```
-rw------- 1 root   88039 Sep 29 16:31 7CCE2EC3-3191-4379-C036-1C48CCCE4C6C
-rw------- 1 root 1985554 Sep 27 16:09 61C6DCDC-04C6-5137-8894-2C8930251D1E
-rw------- 1 root  248965 Sep 26 14:12 22384DC7-D60E-57CC-94C2-C5301C980990 -> MYOLDFILE1
-rw------- 1 root  293908 Sep 22 18:27 C14E6C74-C301-49CC-C625-070721CC47C1
-rw------- 1 root  120965 Sep 19 19:17 2407C1C5-D09C-41E1-9080-C2CC8C86D0CC -> MYNEWFILE.TXT
-rw------- 1 root   20036 Sep 13 18:32 78691D77-C4E6-4ED1-8119-C09CCC194892
-rw------- 1 root   11789 Sep 12 23:16 8C8C190C-5340-421C-96D1-D4111C5E062C -> hello.c
-rw------- 1 root    1884 Sep 11 22:07 CCC91959-9744-4339-9C99-0C75E301090C
```

I tried to do something with `ln -s` but then I end up with a lot of duplicates cause the links are in the same directory and to get a nice view I must filter ls with grep..
any help appreciated

Comment: Do you want `attr`, i.e. extended attributes?

Comment: Is this a `ls` output? It seems that you are using `-L` option (with some other to hide group or owner). Try `/bin/ls -l`

Comment: yes those are outputs from an `ll` alias which is currently defined as `ls -alF`, I don't care about ownerships and / or attributes

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can reliably (mis)use any available feature to make regular `ls` (with or without options) do what you want. You need to redefine `ls` with a script, a function or an alias.

I wouldn't redefine `ls` itself though, at least not in this example, which is meant to be **a simple proof of concept**. Supporting command line switches of `ls` would make the example overly complex.

To implement my solution you need a filesystem supporting extended attributes and tools to manipulate them (e.g. `apt-get install attr` in Debian).

To set the attribute:

```
setfattr -n user.mytag -v "hello.c" "8C8C190C-5340-421C-96D1-D4111C5E062C"
```

Note: `mytag` is an arbitrary name. Choose one and stick to it.

To remove the attribute:

```
setfattr -x user.mytag "8C8C190C-5340-421C-96D1-D4111C5E062C"
```

You can build custom scripts or functions to do these things in a more convenient way. Now let's say you choose `ll` to do what you want. If it's an alias, you need to unalias it first:

```
unalias ll
```

Then define a function:

```
function ll() { find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -exec \
   sh -c '
      a=$(getfattr -n user.mytag --only-values "$1" 2>/dev/null)
      ls -dalF -- "$1" | tr -d "\n"
      if [ -z "$a" ]; then printf "\n"; else printf " => %s\n" "$a"; fi
   ' sh {} \;
}
```

Usage examples:

```
ll   # but see notes below
ll 8C8C190C-5340-421C-96D1-D4111C5E062C
ll /bin
ll foo.txt bar.txt
```

Example output:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 11789 Sep 12 23:16 8C8C190C-5340-421C-96D1-D4111C5E062C => hello.c
```

Notes:

- I used `=>`, not `->`, because the latter is already used by `ls` for symlinks.
- POSIX requires at least one path in `find` invocation. Sole `ll` (with no arguments) may cause `find` to fail (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1322373/432690)). If so, you will need some preliminary logic to pass `.` to `find`.
- `-maxdepth` is not POSIX either. In case you can't use it, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/108618).
- The function simply passes all its arguments to `find` (as `"$@"`). This means this custom `ll` doesn't understand options normally used by `ls` (or common `ll` alias). On the other hand injecting tests into `find` is possible.
- Special or unprintable characters in names or tags may cause unexpected output.
- `ls -dalF` is called for every object separately, so the resulting lines may not align into regular columns. Consider `-printf` action instead of `ls` to print all the information you need, except the tag which will still require `getfattr`. Using tab as a separator in `-printf` format will columnize a multi-line output (at least to some sort). Note that with proper `-printf` format you won't need `tr`.