# What's the alternative for `find -type d` on Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

On Linux `find -type d` works to list all sub directories, ignoring files.

However when I run this on a Mac (High Sierra) I get the error: `find: illegal option -- t`.

On delving into the googles, I hadn't found any obvious alternative for a command line equivalent except for answers suggesting that I use `ls` and parse the output via `grep`, or have solutions for GUI apps or for the non command line users (via finder, etc.).

The usecase would be to pipe this output to a fuzzy finder which expects a newline separated list of items. For example I can accomplish this with files and `ripgrep` with: `rg --files -g "" | fzy`. Ripgrep doesn't seem to support a `--folders` option or the like from my cursory browse on the github issue tracker.

On Linux `find -type d | fzy` "just works". Up to installing other packages, but I really hoped for something that just comes preinstalled.

I can get away from this with some scripting, but I'd love to hear about a best practice here.

Answer (score 6):

I think your `find` *does* understand `-type d` because this is [required by POSIX](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1P/find/). However the syntax you used:

```
find -type d
```

is not POSIX-compliant, thus not portable. The proper portable syntax is:

```
find path -type d
```

Linux versions of `find` will assume `./` if you omit `path`. On Mac `find` expects something [like this](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html):

```
find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
```

You want `-type` to be a part of `expression` but your `find` needs `path` or `-f path` in its command line arguments. Before it gets one, it tries to interpret other arguments as options, so your `-type` is in fact `-t -y -p -e`; there is no `-t` option defined, thus `illegal option -- t`.

(Compare [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369785/108618)).

The solution is simple: specify a `path` explicitly. Mac equivalent of Linux `find -type d` is:

```
find ./ -type d
```

Note this works in Linux as well.

Comment: I've always used the dot without the slash and it works fine (I never realised it even worked without the dot in Linux). I'm just curious if this is a bad habit in general?

Comment: @paradroid Probably not a bad habit. I just tend to add trailing slash to indicate the object is a directory. In some circumstances [this can make a difference](https://superuser.com/a/1320435/432690) though.