# OSX Command line Find Duplicate Filenames with different extensions

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal, applescript

I've gone through all the similar questions + installed few command line utilities like duff but with no sucess.

In my Images directory, I have images with same name but with different extensions (jpg & png). I just want to print the filenames of duplicate filename with different extensions. (e.g. foo.jpg & foo.png) Or at least one file name (foo)

So far I tried these methods

```
find . -exec bash -c 'basename "$0" ".${0##*.}"' {} \; | sort | uniq

find . -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" \)
```

Most of these commands returns me the either **Nothing** OR **All the files** OR **unique** filenames but not the **Duplicate ones**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest a modification of your second command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" | \
    while read -r f; do [ -e "${f%.jpg}.png" ] && echo "${f%.jpg}"; done
```

This finds all `.jpg` files and checks if the corresponding `.png` file exists, and displays the full path without the extensions.

Note that if there are a lot fewer `.png` files it will be more efficient to search for these and check for the corresponding `.jpg` files.

[Tested with `bash` on Ubuntu 18.04.1.]

Comment: find: illegal option -- t

Comment: @ToughGuy - I didn't use any `-t` option, but on Linux `find .` is implicit if no directory is given, and maybe it isn't on OSX. I have added the `.` and quoted the file name in the `echo` in case you have some some odd file names which could appear as options.

Comment: `-type` is normally understood by OSX find according to [this](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html)

Comment: Yes, [`find` on Mac requires `.` or any path](https://superuser.com/a/1322373/432690), POSIX requires it. Here on Super User I advise never omit `.` for the sake of portability.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Thanks: there are things I have just got used to doing. Without a Mac, I can't check every option of every command in case it's not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I accept and appreciate the answer. Meanwhile I got this python script that worked somewhat near to what I was looking for. I tried to find the source but couldn't find it in 100's of tabs I searched.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Syntax: duplicates.py DIRECTORY
import os, sys
top = sys.argv[1]
d = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
  for name in files:
    fn = os.path.join(root, name)
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(name)

    basename = basename.lower() # ignore case

    if basename in d:
        print(d[basename])
        print(fn)
    else:
        d[basename] = fn
```

Save this file as duplicates.py and give it rights and then execute it on the folder.

```
./duplicates.py Images
```

Comment: Matching on name and alternate suffixes is useful but it doesn't guarantee the files are actual duplicates.  You would need to include comparison of file sizes and if they match actually compare the file contents.

Comment: @Hogstorm Good idea but my requirement was different. There are plenty of utilities apps for duplicate finder but none was promising as I needed the output in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `uniq -c` to get the counts, then reverse-sort at the end to list the duplicates first. At the end `awk` is used to filter for lines that start with 2 or higher.

```
$ find . -type f -exec sh -c 'basename ${0%.*}' {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | awk 'int($1)>=2'
   2 foo
```

Here, `%.*` strips the extension, so `foo.x.y` becomes `foo.x`.

Instead of a simple `find . -type f`, which would find all files, you could also filter for `*.jpg` or `*.png` files like in your second command.

Comment: Certainly it gave me a long list of all the files with the count of duplicates. Can I get only the duplicates? (e.g. foo which is used twice or thrice)